# In Excel 2016 VBA, how can I get an IF statement to run if it finds a match in a table?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to keep a table of dates that members of a team last had a review with their manager. I've made a sheet where the name of the colleague, the team they work in, the manager's name and the date of the review are can be input along with a button that submits this data to the table on the second sheet.

What I would like is that when you press the submit button the code searches the table to see if an entry already exists for that colleague, and if so to update the date and manager name for the entry, and if no match is found then it creates a new entry at the bottom of the table.

I've created an IF statement, however when running it, it skips straight to the Else condition even if "colleague_name" matches "data_colleague_name". For example if I enter Joe Bloggs into the input field ("colleague_name", which refers to =Input!$E$3 in the Name Manager) and there is already an entry for Joe Bloggs in the table ("data_colleague_name", which refers to =Table2[Colleague Name] in the Name Manager), it adds a second entry for Joe Bloggs at the end of the table. This is the current IF statement, I've not included the ELSE statement as that works fine:

```
If No IsError(Application.Match("colleague_name", "data_colleague_name", 0)) Then

    dest_row = Application.Cell("row", Application.Index("Table 2", Application.Match("colleage_name", "data_colleague_name", 0)))
    Sheets(ws_output).Cells(dest_row, 3).Value = Range("manager_name").Value
    Sheets(ws_outout).Cells(dest_row, 4).Value = Range("review_date").Value
```

In the above Joe Bloggs example, if I step through the code using debug it skips straight to the ELSE condition even though there is a match in the table. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `"colleague_name"` and `"data_colleague_name"` are just text... you need to actually refer to a `Range` it sounds like.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted that bit!